# Agregar categoría/filtrar a usuarios por escuela (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Tengo un sitio en Wordpress con muchos profesores, quiero una opción donde pueda saber a que escuela pertenece.

Los profesores y escuelas son usuarios con diferentes roles.

Una opción podría ser de darle una categoría a cada profesor o agregarlos a un grupo.

*(Puede ser un plugin o código)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crea categorías con el nombre de cada colegio y luego asigna a cada profesor su categoría correspondiente, luego por código puedes obtener todos los profesores que pertenezcan a cada colegio.

```
<?php

$args = [
  'post_type' => 'profesores',
  'category_name' => 'nombre-del-colegio',
  'posts_per_page' => -1 // Obtienes todos los profesores, aunque puedes cambiar ese numero.
];

$profesores = get_posts($args);

foreach($profesores as $profesor):
  // code
endforeach;
```